# How to execute and log as specific user?

Tags: bash, shell, permissions, stdout, sudo

I need to run a command/shell-script as on other user. The stdout shall be written to a logfile.

I tried it like this:

```
export LOGDIR=foo/bar
sudo -u www command /home/www > /home/www/$LOGDIR/command.log
```

But I get always this error:

```
-bash: /home/www/foo/bar/command.log: Permission denied
```

You can try this easily with this little stupid example:

```
sudo -u edeviser ls /home/edeviser > /home/edeviser/$LOGDIR/ls.log
```

I see the problem is, that the redirection with `>` is not done as the user specified by the ´-u´ option.

**How to execute the command and log as the same specific user?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like

```
sudo -u www bash -c "command /home/www > /home/www/$LOGDIR/command.log"
```

Comment: Hmmm, I think `$LOGDIR` is not resolved if it is quoted with `"`!?

Comment: `$LOGDIR` won't be expanded when quoted with single quotes `'`, but double quotes `"` allows the shell to expand the parameters. Anyways... try it!

Answer (score 1):

```
export logdir="foo/bar"
sudo -u www command /home/www |sudo -u www dd of="/home/www/$logdir/command.log"
```